# How to use Google Apps Script to set the "values" and "go to section based on answer" for a Google Form dropdown?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I using Google Sheets to store the "values" and "go to section based on answer" for a Google Form dropdown. How can I use the Google Apps Script to set both "values" and "go to section based on answer" for the dropdown?

I am able to set values from Google Sheet using the script, but I am not able to set the "go to section based on answer" for the drop-down using the sheet and script.

I already have the `listItem` of the dropdown in the script which I am using to set values. I tried using `createChoice(value, navigationItem)` and with it to set the "go to section" and then used `setChoiceValues(values)` but I everything gets set as "Choice" on the form.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a sample of the code you are working on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to create a dropdown item that takes you to a different section depending on the choice using Apps Script:

```
function createDropdownExample() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('your_form_id');
  var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  item.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?');  
  var dogsPage = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Dogs');
  var catsPage = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Cats');
  var dogsChoice = item.createChoice('Dogs', dogsPage);
  var catsChoice = item.createChoice('Cats', catsPage);
  item.setChoices([dogsChoice, catsChoice]);
}
```

Comment: I already have a drop down created on the form and I am using script to populate the values of the dropdown from google sheet. So, if any value(s) is changed in the sheet, it is automatically reflect in the dropdown list.   Everything works fine till this point. Now, I also want to set the  "go to section based on answer" for each of these choices using the script. The reason I want to use the script is because there are many choices and they may keep changing. So, if I can use the data stored in sheet to set both the "value" and the "go to section" for each choice, that would be ideal.

Comment: The code I posted can set values and "go to section" dynamically, just change 'Dogs' and 'Cats' by whatever value is in the sheet.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Yes, I did exactly what you suggested! Thanks!

Comment: All right. Also, for documentation purposes, remember that in order to mark your question as solved you can accept one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 3):

This a version of the above with values from a spreadsheet:

```
function GoToPage() {
var form = FormApp.openById('MY FORM');
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MY SPREADSHEET");
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MY SHEET");
var list = form.getItemById("MY MULTIPLE CHOICE ID").asListItem()  
var pagebreak01 = form.getItemById("PAGE BREAK ID 1").asPageBreakItem();
var pagebreak02 = form.getItemById("PAGE BREAK ID 2").asPageBreakItem();
var pagebreak03 = form.getItemById("PAGE BREAK ID 3").asPageBreakItem();
var choice1 = sheet.getRange("RANGE 1 FROM MY SHEET").getValues();
var choice2 = sheet.getRange("RANGE 2 FROM MY SHEET").getValues();
var choice3 = sheet.getRange("RANGE 3 FROM MY SHEET").getValues();  
list.setChoices([
  list.createChoice(choice1, pagebreak01),
  list.createChoice(choice2, pagebreak02),
  list.createChoice(choice3, pagebreak03)]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `setChoiceValues(values)` instead of using `setChoices(choices)`. When I made this correction, I was able to set the "go to section" dynamically.