# How to use Script to modify Google Form question that contains conditions, and add "other" option?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

## Task

I have a Google Form (see simplified [test form here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScewmq15oT8YOZst10acY_76lOgXMm2I347mTcWBmGsuQOzCg/viewform)) that sends the submissions to a Google Spreadsheet (see [test sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XJob-4T_N4asSQfRQO_pIrhoF4oaDnkFjclqa-Unpao/edit?usp=sharing)). Every multiple choice question includes an "other" option.

Upon submission of the form to the sheet, a Script function `updateGoogleForm()` is triggered (deactivated in the test sheet, code below) that modifies the Google Form so that the new "other" mentions become part of the pre-defined response choices.

## Three challenges:

1. **I cannot modify the response choices of questions that have "Go to section based on answer" conditions** attached to the choices (such as 'Question 2' in the test form). Trying this with `setChoiceValues(MY_VALUES)` will throw an `Exception: Invalid data updating form.` My workaround is to completely delete and reconstruct the respective question to retain the skip logic (done in the code snippet below for Question 2).
2. **However, deleting and re-adding the same question will create a new column in the sheet that receives the responses** (starting in column H of the [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XJob-4T_N4asSQfRQO_pIrhoF4oaDnkFjclqa-Unpao/edit?usp=sharing)), despite using the same question wording/title, i.e. it is treated as a completely new question, making it difficult to analyze the results. Can I avoid this?
3. **I cannot add an "other" option to questions that contain skip conditions**, at least not by using `showOtherOption(true)`, as seen in the code example below - it also throws the exception `Invalid data updating form`. Is there another way to do this programmatically?

## Example

Here is the workaround function that deletes and rebuilds the question to be modified:

```
const updateGoogleForm = () => {
  
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = 'Choices_for_form'; // Name of sheet in the Google spreadsheet that this script is linked to
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = '<form_id>'; // ID of the Google Form
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get active (this) Google SHEET that contains the survey responses and response options
  const form = FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID); // Get our Google FORM to be edited
  const formSections = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK); // Get all page breaks in form
  var formSectionIDsByTitle = [];
  for (i in formSections) formSectionIDsByTitle[formSections[i].getTitle()] = formSections[i].getId(); // Make an associative array of page break IDs that can be accessed by the section title
  
  // Get all data of the spreadsheet that contains the response options (one question per column)
  const [header, ...data] = ss
    .getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME)
    .getDataRange()
    .getDisplayValues();
  
  // Write response options to an array that has the question titles as its keys and the response options as values
  const choices = {};
  header.forEach((title, i) => {
    choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e); // For each question item, store response options (choices) in array
  });

  // Iterate over all question items and replace the response options in the form
  const formItems = form.getItems(); // Get all question items from form
  for (i = 0; i < formItems.length; i++) {
    
    var itemTitle = formItems[i].getTitle() || null; // Get question title (label)
    if (!itemTitle || (itemTitle && !choices.hasOwnProperty(itemTitle))) continue; // If we don't have values for this question in the spreadsheet, skip
    
    var valuesToUse = choices[itemTitle];
    var itemType = formItems[i].getType();
    
    Logger.log("Updating item ID=" + formItems[i].getId(), ', TYPE=' + itemType + ', item title="' + itemTitle + '"');
    
    // Replace response choices depending on the question type
    switch (itemType) {
        case itemType.CHECKBOX:
          formItems[i].asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(valuesToUse);
          break;
        case itemType.LIST:
          formItems[i].asListItem().setChoiceValues(valuesToUse);
          break;
        case itemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
        
          // Simply setting new choices for questions that contain skip conditions ("Go to section based on answer")
          // will throw an exception ("Invalid data updating form."), therefore reconstructing this question entirely.
          if (itemTitle=='Question 2: What is your favorite animal?') { // This is the question that requires skipping sections based on answers
            Logger.log('Rebuilding the question directing conditional skips.');
            form.deleteItem(formItems[i].getIndex()); // Delete the current item and replace it with a new item
            var newItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle('Question 2: What is your favorite animal?'); // Recreate the question item with the added options and add conditional skips
            newItem.setHelpText('You can add multiple "other" options by separating them with a comma (,) each');
            var eventTypeChoices = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < valuesToUse.length; j++) {
              if (valuesToUse[j] == 'Cat') 
                  eventTypeChoices.push(newItem.createChoice(valuesToUse[j], form.getItemById(formSectionIDsByTitle['Questions about cats']).asPageBreakItem()));
                else if (valuesToUse[j] == 'Dog')
                  eventTypeChoices.push(newItem.createChoice(valuesToUse[j], form.getItemById(formSectionIDsByTitle['Questions about dogs']).asPageBreakItem()));
                else
                  eventTypeChoices.push(newItem.createChoice(valuesToUse[j], form.getItemById(formSectionIDsByTitle['Concluding section for everyone']).asPageBreakItem()));
            }
            // Assign response choices to the newly re-built question
            newItem.setChoices(eventTypeChoices).setRequired(true);
            //newItem.showOtherOption(true); // This doesn't work because the question contains choices that require "going to section based on answer" (conditional skips)
            form.moveItem(newItem.getIndex(), formSections[0].getIndex()); // Need move the question into its original place (end of first section, section index = 0)
          }
          else {
            // This is a "regular" multiple choice item without condition skips,
            // we can simply replace the choices
            formItems[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(valuesToUse);
          }
          break;
        default:
        // ignore other items
      }
  }
  Logger.log('Google Form updated successfully!');
};
```

## Solution for example

This is the working solution as proposed by [Alessandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7453656/alessandro) for the code example used above. Instead of deleting and rebuilding the question, this snippet modifies the existing question item.

As a precondition, the question needs to be set up in the form via UI with `navigationType` for all choices, including the "other" option.

The trick was to get the question again as multiple choice item `var theQuestion = form.getItemById(formItems[i].getId()).asMultipleChoiceItem()` and work with this to create and set the choices.

[This earlier post contains a similar solution for a static form.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60120251/5389846)

```
case itemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
  if (itemTitle=='Question 2: What is your favorite animal?') { // This is the only question containing navigationType
    var theQuestion = form.getItemById(formItems[i].getId()).asMultipleChoiceItem();
    var newChoices = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < valuesToUse.length; j++) {
      if (valuesToUse[j] ==  'Cat') 
        newChoices.push(theQuestion.createChoice(valuesToUse[j], form.getItemById(formSectionIDsByTitle['Questions about cats']).asPageBreakItem()));
      else if (valuesToUse[j] == 'Dog')        
        newChoices.push(theQuestion.createChoice(valuesToUse[j], form.getItemById(formSectionIDsByTitle['Questions about dogs']).asPageBreakItem()));
      else 
        newChoices.push(theQuestion.createChoice(valuesToUse[j], form.getItemById(formSectionIDsByTitle['Concluding section for everyone']).asPageBreakItem()));
    }
    theQuestion.setChoices(newChoices);
  }
  else {             
     formItems[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(valuesToUse);
  }
  break;
```

I could not make this work by directly using `formItems[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice()` and neither `formItems[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoices()`. This threw `Exception: Invalid conversion for item type: TEXT.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

#### 1) Array of Choices must be consistent

You cannot use the `setChoiceValues(MY_VALUES)` because the question you are updating is expecting a Choice instances of the type `(value, navigationType)`.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue,-navigationtype):

> Choices that use page navigation cannot be combined in the same item with choices that do not use page navigation.

#### 2) Update the existing question with `.setChoices()`

You can update the question you need using the same code you are using to create a new question. Be sure to build a consistent array of Choices containing a `navigationType` parameter.

#### 3) Adding the "Other" option

The "Other" option can only be programmatically set on choices without `navigationType` parameters. This happens to be a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171782147): currently, you can only create this option from the UI for choices that contain `navigationType` parameters.

If the "Other" option is already set with the proper `navigationType` you can use the `setChoices(choices)` to update an existing question.

### Reference

[createChoice(value, navigationType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createchoicevalue,-navigationtype)

Comment: Perfect, thank you, this is what I was looking for. I incorporated your suggested solution in the question above to show how it works with the example I used. I was struggling to make the solution work by directly working with `formItems[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice()`. Instead, I retrieved the item again asMultipleChoiceItem by Id, then worked with this. Thanks again!