# Go_TO_PAGE in Google Form by apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want a dynamic form from a Google sheet.

Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13oYduqhOicLEuAJOPBnx8kymyUhz9tnBdDjubfn1ubY/edit#gid=1215856726

Form
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/111Dqn_IJJn-QufnuZrvixToV_JsKZTzMx6eJcv3kfzk/edit

The number of questions is dynamic (can change)
Number of Pages is also dynamic (corresponding to questions)
Number of question in a page is also dynamic(max 10)

I was able to make the form by app script.

But, I am not able to link the drop down questions to the corresponding page (with the same name)

I tried many examples in SO. None is working.

TypeError: item.createChoice is not a function

```
//
function updateForm(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  var qsht=ss.getSheetByName("Questions")
  var qvals=qsht.getDataRange().getValues()
  var form = FormApp.openById("111Dqn_IJJn-QufnuZrvixToV_JsKZTzMx6eJcv3kfzk")
  var items = form.getItems();
  //remove multiple choice for Q9
  //this is required so that any linked page can be deleted
  var multipleChoices=[]
  for (i=1;i<qvals.length;i++){
    multipleChoices.push(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1])
  }
  var formList = FormApp.ItemType.LIST;
  var formItems = form.getItems(formList);
  formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(multipleChoices);
  //formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues([""]);
  var item=formItems[0]
  Logger.log("apply for item "+item.getType())
  Logger.log("apply for "+item.getTitle())
  //delete all job items aftr 9
  for (var i=items.length-1; i>9; i--){
    form.deleteItem(i)
  }
  var choices=[]
  //create all new sections 
  for (var i=1; i<qvals.length; i++ ){
    var pgBreakItem=form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1])
    .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
    Logger.log("pg brk type "+pgBreakItem.getType())
    Logger.log("pg brk title "+pgBreakItem.getTitle())
    Logger.log("item label "+qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1])
    choices.push(item.createChoice(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1],pgBreakItem));
}
item.setChoices(choices)
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. And, I cannot understand the relationship between `The number of questions is dynamic (can change) Number of Pages is also dynamic (corresponding to questions) Number of question in a page is also dynamic(max 10)` and your Speradsheet and your expected Google Form. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I was able to add drop down choices to the Q9. I want that each question will lead to a section (with the same name as the choice selected)

Comment: Your question must stand on its own. Users should not have to open your spreadsheet/form to understand your question. `I am not able to link the drop down questions to the corresponding page (with the same name)` and `I was able to add drop down choices to the Q9. I want that each question will lead to a section (with the same name as the choice selected)` - these are vague because the question doesn't provide any content or example. Please edit your question to include a comprehensive description of your scenario (with examples) and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was able to add choices for a drop down list by var form = FormApp.openById("111Dqn_IJJn-QufnuZrvixToV_JsKZTzMx6eJcv3kfzk")
  var items = form.getItems();
  //add multiple choice for Q9
  var multipleChoices=[]
  for (i=1;i<qvals.length;i++){
    multipleChoices.push(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1])
  }
  var formList = FormApp.ItemType.LIST;
  var formItems = form.getItems(formList);
  formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(multipleChoices);
  //. What I'm not able to do is adding a go-to-page to the choice

Comment: related question: [How to use Google Apps Script to set the "values" and "go to section based on answer" for a Google Form dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58423352/1330560)

Comment: Thank you. I used the same logic in a loop (the number of sections is dynamic). But, I'm getting error item.createChoice is not a function: var choices=[];   for (var i=1; i<qvals.length; i++ ){
    var pgBreakItem=form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1])
    .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
    Logger.log("pg brk type"+pgBreakItem.getType())
    Logger.log("pg brk title "+pgBreakItem.getTitle())
    Logger.log("item label "+qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1])
    choices.push(item.createChoice(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1],pgBreakItem));}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Tedinoz.
The link helped.
related question: How to use Google Apps Script to set the "values" and "go to section based on answer" for a Google Form dropdown? –
Tedinoz

Instead of editing the List item, first I deleted it and created it every time and it worked well.

If trying to edit an existing list item, it was not working.

The working code is now much smaller.

```
function updateForm(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  var qsht=ss.getSheetByName("Questions")
  var qvals=qsht.getDataRange().getValues()
  var form = FormApp.openById("")
  var items = form.getItems();
  if (items.length>=9){items[9].asListItem().setChoiceValues([""])};//required so that linked sections can be deleted
  //delete all items after 8
  for (var i=items.length-1; i>8; i--){
    form.deleteItem(i)
  }
  var choices=[]
  //create all new sections 
  var item = form.addListItem();
  item.setTitle('Applying For').setRequired(true);  
  for (var i=1; i<qvals.length; i++ ){
    var pgBreakItem=form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1])
    .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
    choices.push(item.createChoice(qvals[i][0]+" "+qvals[i][1],pgBreakItem));
    for (var j=8; j<17; j++){
    if (qvals[i][j]!==""){
      form.addParagraphTextItem().setTitle(qvals[i][j]).setRequired(true)
    }
  }
  
  item.setChoices(choices)
}
```