# Branching in quiz Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have seen a couple of videos in internet that shows how to create an 'interactive' quiz, with tell you, after every response, It it is ritght or wrong. I would like to add such functionality to my form creating script.

I have an script to create a Google Form importing the questions from Google Sheet. My sheet has one row per question, with six columns (first is question, next four are options, and last one is the correct answer item):

```
var data = mySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var numberOfQuestions = data.length;

var myForm = FormApp.create('Ramdom Quiz').setIsQuiz(true);

myForm.setTitle('RandomQuiz');

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions ; i++) {
    //Read data
    var question = data[i][0];
    var answers = data[i].slice(1, 5);
    var rightAnswer = data[i][5];
    var righrAnswerIndex = data[i][5] - 1;

    //Create Multiple Choide Question
    var item = formulario.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    //Question
    item.setTitle(pregunta);
    //AnswerOptions (with correct answer)
    var options = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
      options.push(item.createChoice(answers[j], j === righrAnswerIndex));
    }
    item.setChoices(opciones);
    item.setPoints(1);
}
```

How can I?:

- Have each question in a different section: I need to create the section for each question and keep some sort of index or reference to point for navigation.
- Quiz will move to next section (with another question) only if answer is right: I suppose that, for navigation, I can use *'createChoice(value, navigationItem)'*, but I create the choices with *'createChoice(value, isCorrect)'*. There is no function that allows me to set isCorrect and navigationItem for each choice.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Where would the form navigate to if the user got an answer wrong? I don't believe you can halt/pause a form, based on a multiple choice item. You might consider a regex limitation, but that gets more complex.

Comment: As a workaround, you can have the form navigate to the current section (essentially preventing them from progressing) until the correct answer is selected. You are correct that there's no function to set both `isCorrect` and `navigationItem` for each choice but is it necessary to specify a correct option? Users would have to get all of the answers correct in order to submit the form or they would not be able to submit it at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Google Apps Script to set the "values" and "go to section based on answer" for a Google Form dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423352/how-to-use-google-apps-script-to-set-the-values-and-go-to-section-based-on-an)